# UIDocumentInteractionController hides behind navigation bar when status bar is bigger (Personal Hotspot title)

Tags: ios, ios8

So title sey it exactly UIDocumentInteractionController hides behind navigation bar when status bar is bigger in height because of Personal Hotspot title. I am giving it my navigationController. Looks like IOS bug. Any solutions or workaround ?

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *pdfViewer = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
[pdfViewer setDelegate:self];
[pdfViewer presentPreviewAnimated:YES];

- (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview (UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {
    return self.navigationController;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is my 'BAD' solution. This code uses my custom classes. What it does should be readable. It is updating each second navigationBar and first controller from navigation controllers array so it should be controller presented by UIDocumentInteractionController at some point. Everything works nicely now.

```
 _updateNavigationBarStyle = [self schedule:1 :^{
    self.navigation.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.navigation.topViewController.view.top = self.navigation.navigationBar.bottom;
}].start;

- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {
    [_updateNavigationBarStyle stop];
```

}

Answer (score -2):

Try clicking on your UIDocumentInteractionController file, and then do Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller.

Comment: I seriously don't know what are you talking about...  UIDocumentInteractionController is IOS class it is not UI class it is not descendant of UINavigationController it is just NSObject... And also I don't do anything with it in designer... So where is your answer coming from ? Can you post some code ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I got a little confused with the question, but now I get it.  This does look like a bug, but your idea of creating a class to fix the navigation controller was a smart idea.